# CCM, DCM and BCM - Inductor

Tags: voltage, current, diodes, dc-dc-converter, boost

In a boost converter, what is the factor that determines whether the power supply (dc-dc converter) will be in the CCM, BCM or DCM mode?

Because, I have an LED Driver [A80604](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/regulate/led-drivers/led-drivers-for-backlighting/a80601). And I am trying to calculate the inductor value for it.

Input Voltage = 9.5V to 16V

LED string = 9 LEDs (each Vf of 3.1V and If=0.3A)

Output voltage = 30V

Output Current = 300mA

In this case, I have been following the design example from page 35.

I have got to this point :

Vout_typ = 30.64V & Vf_schottky=0.52V. Vbat = 9.5V, 13.5V & 16V (Min, typ and Max)

[image]

[image]

Are my above calculations, right?

My questions:

1. What is the factor that determines whether the power supply (dc-dc converter) will be in the CCM, BCM or DCM mode?
2. What is the required inductor value that I need to choose for this application which requires constant current for the LEDs?

Comment: I left you an interactive calculator link on your previous question in comments. You should enter a few values and see what you get. Operating frequency is needed.

Comment: Operating frequency is 455kHz.. Can you please tell me what deternines the CCM and other modes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What is the factor that determines whether the power supply (dc-dc
> converter) will be in the CCM, BCM or DCM mode?*

The dominant factor is load current. If the load current goes beyond a certain value the boost converter will operate in continuous conduction mode: -

[image]

On lighter loads the boost converter will operate in discontinuous conduction mode: -

[image]

And, at exactly one point, DCM and CCM look the same - this is called boundary conduction mode.

> *What is the required inductor value that I need to choose for this
> application which requires constant current for the LEDs?*

If you want to run in CCM (probably the likely choice) then if the input voltage is 12 volts, the output voltage is 30 volts, the output current is 300 mA and the operating frequency is 455 kHz then, the minimum inductance value is around 12 μH: -

[image]

<sub>Note that I set the output voltage to be 30.7 volts to accommodate the forward drop of a real diode. The dotted lines in the above graph show the BCM point. If the converter current waveform fell below that BCM line, you'd be in DCM.</sub>

However, that gives over 1.3 amps of input supply ripple current and you may choose to make the inductor a lot bigger such as 100 μH: -

[image]

Now, the ripple current is 0.847 amps minus 0.686 amps = 161 mA

I expect somewhere between the two will be the right answer but, you can use the [interactive boost tool](http://www.stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html) to try out different scenarios.

Your value range from 39 μH to 91 μH is going to be about right. My low end value of 12 μH might cause the boost circuit to drop into DCM mode on a lower load current and sometimes, that can cause stability problems.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. 1.3A of inductor ripple current? In my calculations, it is less. What am I thinking wrong here?

Comment: That's with an inductor of 12 uH. With 100 uH, ripple current is only 161 mA. Also remember that my tool (in the pictures) is an ideal boost converter representation that gives a reasonable idea but doesn't take into account MOSFET switching losses.

Comment: So, the lower inductor value, higher inductor ripple current?

Comment: @Newbie correct and, if you carry on making it lower, the converter will drop from CCM to DCM.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I have seen a few application notes from TI and others. All of them are explaining about the CCM, DCM and BCM concepts with respect to the discrete circuit components. Circuits only with Inductors, Diodes, Mosfet and Load. No application note is explaining about the concept of CCM or DCM with respect to a particular IC. So, whether the concept of conduction modes is controlled by the ICs itself (Buck or Boost converter ICs)? Whether we change the inductor values of the Buck and Boost converter, the conduction mode would not change?

Comment: The "chip" is just a controller; it alters duty cycle to make the output voltage (or current) the right amount. Those chips will freely swap between CCM and DCM depending on inductor value, input/output requirements and switching frequency but, the main decider is load current.

Comment: *Whether we change the inductor values of the Buck and Boost converter, the conduction mode would not change?* - yes it can change even if load current is constant - look at my first simulated boost converter picture. It's right on the border of dropping into DCM - if I make the inductor value lower (like 10 uH from 12 uH), it'll drop into DCM. Look at my 2nd simulation - it has an inductor value of 100 uA and is firmly operating in CCM.

Comment: I'm trying to understand slowly. "If the load current goes beyond a certain value the boost converter will operate in continuous conduction mode" - When you say this, what is the limit? When you mentioned, "beyond" a certain value, could you please clarify a little more? Is this statement with respect to some buck/boost IC or buck/boost circuit with discrete components?

Comment: "My low end of 12 μH might cause the boost circuit to drop into CCM mode on a lower load and sometimes that can makes stability problems." - Do you mean DCM ?

Comment: Oops yes, drop from CCM into DCM.

Comment: To understand where the limit is between CCM and DCM you have to develop what it means to operate exactly at the boundary. If you operate exactly at the boundary condition then, any reduction in load current, inductance or operating frequency will take you into DCM. Any increase of those things takes you into CCM. So far, are you happy with that because, it is the boundary condition calculation that is what you need to understand next and, that has some complexity. However, it is explained on the link to my website in the answer. I can help you through this step by step if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'll try to understand and do my study and come back here in a few hours.

Comment: @Newbie I tried to make the website as clear as I could so, given it is my website, if you want, you can conduct this conversation away from SE.EE by contacting me on my EE email (info@ link on [this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/20218/andy-aka?tab=profile)). It's a useful exercise for me because it might help me improve my website.

Comment: Sure, thank you very much for your support. I will read and try the tool in your website. Will contact you tomorrow over EE email

Comment: Shall I contact you in mail, right now?

Comment: You should concentrate on understanding why the slopes of the inductor's current are related to input voltage and output voltage - that is crucial and that bit may take a time to sink in because inductors are not everyone's favourite component.

Comment: You can email now or tomorrow. I'll respond.

Comment: Sure, thank you. In the 2 scenarios that you have given, 12uH and the 100uH, with the same input and output load conditions, with same duty cycle, the Peak current decreases. I understand like, Higher the inductance, Higher the resistance and less the current rise for the given time and hence less peak current. But, the average current is 766mA. And the output current is 300mA. Why is there a difference? I understand, I'm missing something silly. Is that difference in current, stored in the magnetic field during the ON time ?

Comment: Input voltage x average input current = output voltage x output current.- 12 volts x 0.766 = 9.192 watts AND 30.7 volts x 0.3 amps = 9.21 watts (rounding errors of 0.2% accounts for the difference). In other words, power in equals power out for a 100% efficiency.

Comment: So, the 0.766A is the average input current. Correct? And the Boost converter tool used in the your site, is applicable to BOOST CONVERTER in general, right? It'd work even if the IC part is an LED Driver or a Normal Boost IC from TI. Just for clarification

Comment: It's a generic tool but assumes perfection in power transfer and zero diode losses hence why I made the output voltage 30.7 volts so that the forward drop of the diode is accounted for.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122544/discussion-between-andy-aka-and-newbie).