Why does my boost converter simulation depend on the load resistance?
I made this attempt at a boost converter in EveryCircuit to try and understand how it works:

There's something I'm having a really hard time understanding. This circuit is not obeying the supposed transfer function for a boost converter that I know as: $$\frac {V_{out}} {V_{in}} = \frac 1 {1 - D}$$
I even got this result with my own calculations by hand by setting the open and closed state changes in the inductor current equal to each other.
I'm running on a 50% duty cycle, so I would expect the output voltage on the load resistor to settle down at 18 volts, but it's actually settled down at around 73 volts. Changing the load resistor has a huge impact on where the voltage settles down as well. I'm very confused, I'd appreciate some guidance. Is it just something to do with how I've modeled it in EveryCircuit that's making it behave incorrectly?

Does your equation apply in DCM or CCM? If not, what equation(s) might apply then?

I did some reading on what those terms mean, since I'd never seen them before. I'm unsure still, but I believe I'm in continuous conduction mode for the most part, according to what I've read. (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/557753/ccm-dcm-and-bcm-inductor)

What is your switching frequency, if your duty cycle is 50%? Also, as a hint, you expect the time the FET is on and off to not affect the output voltage at all, only the duty cycle?

I would expect the actual period of the FET's switching to be important, yet negligible at faster speeds. As you can see, the period is 1 ms, so the frequency is 1kHz. I guess a problem is I don't know if that's ridiculously slow

Monitor the inductor current. Whatever the current is when the FET turns off will be the current pumped in to the rectifier and load for a short time before the inductor current goes down to zero. This voltage will be a high voltage spike across the switching FET which is why you can boost the voltage from this circuit.

@qrk I understand that process. What's confusing me is why the output voltage doesn't settle down at 18 volts here on a 50% duty cycle, when sources say the out/input ratio is 1 / (1 - D), which would be 2 in this case

Turns out I was operating in discontinuous conduction mode actually. That question I posted has a really nice simulator actually

You didn't say what operating frequency you were using  @HydroPage

Hi Andy, pleasure to speak with you, I was reading your website earlier. I'm playing around with several frequencies right now, and adjusting things according to your website's numbers. There's something annoying about EveryCircuit though, it doesn't like when I don't put a series resistor on the inductor, it thinks a short circuit happens or something... and something that's confusing me about your explanations is why you seem to ignore a series resistance, first of all, and second, why you pretend the inductor is linear to charge and discharge. Isn't it exponential actually?

@Andyaka I forgot to tag you before, but I'm not sure if it makes a difference to whether you see a response or not

Anyone designing an efficient boost converter will choose an inductor that has very small (or not significant) series resistance losses. You still haven't answered my question regarding what frequency you decided upon in your question when you raised it. This is a question and answer site and not a forum @HydroPage

@Andyaka I'm sorry, but I'm confused about why you ask. Near the first few comments, I said I was using 1 kHz at first, and as you can see in the diagram, the oscillator has a period of 1 ms. Am I misunderstanding something?
